# How to append value in dictionary after parsed "jSON" Data in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-places-api

Here goes my code.

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection){

    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

    if jsonResult.count>0 && jsonResult["results"]!.count>0 {
        var result: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as! NSArray
        println("\(result)")
        var dict = NSDictionary()
        var myDict = NSDictionary()

        for dict in result {
            let googleGeo = dict["geometry"] as! NSDictionary
            let googleLoc = googleGeo["location"] as! NSDictionary
            let latitude = googleLoc["lat"] as! Float
            let longitude = googleLoc["lng"] as! Float
            let googleicon = dict.valueForKey("icon") as? NSString
            let googlename = dict["name"] as? NSString
            let googlevicinity = dict["vicinity"] as? NSString

            myDict.setValue(latitude, forKey: "lat"    
        }
    }
}
```

After parsing from Google Places API, i received longitude, latitude, name, vicinity, icon. Now i want to append these value to myDctionary so that i can pass the value to an array and to the next view controller.

Please someone let me know to to do it ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you are trying to append to which dictionary? Also, what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: Further more: Don't force_cast and try to keep away from using objc functions.

Comment: in what are the values you want to pass

Comment: that lat , log , name and vicinity value , i need to store in my dictionary ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend, you should try this.

Let the dictionary know exactly what type of key/value pairs you want it to hold. You want to use a "String" as the key and since your values have different datatypes you want to use "AnyObject" as the value.

**UPDATE** For Swift 2 you would use String:AnyObject but for Swift3 you would use String:Any. I've updated the code to show the Swift 3 version instead.

```
//this says your dictionary will accept key value pairs as String/Any
var myDict = [String:Any]()
```

You use Any because you have so many different datatypes

```
//Your values have are being cast as NSDictionary, Float, and NSStrings. All different datatypes
let googleGeo = dict["geometry"] as? NSDictionary
let googleLoc = googleGeo["location"] as? NSDictionary
let latitude = googleLoc["lat"] as? Float
let longitude = googleLoc["lng"] as? Float
let googleicon = dict.valueForKey("icon") as? NSString
let googlename = dict["name"] as? NSString
let googlevicinity = dict["vicinity"] as? NSString
```

Now you use the method .updateValue(value: Value, forKey: Hashable) to set your keys and values

```
//update the dictionary with the new values with value-type Any and key-type String
myDict.updateValue(googleGeo, forKey: "geometry")
myDict.updateValue(googleLoc, forKey: "location")
myDict.updateValue(latitude, forKey: "lat")
myDict.updateValue(longitude, forKey: "lng")
myDict.updateValue(googleicon, forKey: "icon")
myDict.updateValue(googlename, forKey: "name")
myDict.updateValue(googlevicinity, forKey: "vicinity")
```

myDict should now have have all these key/value pairs and you do what you want with them by using the key to extract the value. Btw I only used those key names because for your post it seemed that's the convention you was using. You can name the keys whatever you want. But whatever you name them they have to be the same name you use to extract the value.

Hope this helps!